# Display Comment Wrapper for Anonymous users

Tags: forms, theming, comments

I would like to display comment-wrapper.tpl on a node to anonymous users, even though they have to login to comment and even when there are 0 comments on the node. Ideally it would display the wrapper with a "Login or register to comment" underneath. Any ideas?